# Redirect subdirectory names to the index.php for pretty URLs using mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel-4

I have a website on an Apache server, based on a framework (Laravel 4), which comes with an .htaccess file to remove trailing slashes and redirect non-existing files to the index.php for pretty URLs.

I use the first fragment of the URL for localization, like `mysite.com/en/about`. I also have physical language folders for localized resource files, like `/en/images/hello.jpg`

Physical language folders break the URL redirection in the .htaccess file this way:

- `mysite.com/en` automatically redirects to folder root: `mysite.com/en/`
- trailing slash is removed by the .htaccess
- loop!

So `mysite.com/en` can't be used for the language index, and I use `/en/home` as a workaround.

The part from the stock .htaccess file:

```
# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Is it possible to make folder names redirect to the `index.php` too, without hardcoding them. So that;

- `mysite.com/en` is redirected to the `index.php`
- `mysite.com/en/images/about.jpg` brings the related file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem seems to be your trailing slash removal rule. Replace that with this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

This rule will skip directories for trailing slash removal so `/en/` will remain unaffected.

**PS:** Make sure to test this in a new browser to avoid 301 caching issues.

Comment: good point! but then the trailing slash is sent to the index.php, confusing the parser. hmm maybe another rule could be used for directory names to redirect them without the trailing slash... I'll make some tests...

Comment: What do you mean by `then the trailing slash is sent to the index.php`? Note that `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` will skip any directories and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` will skip any files to be sent to `index.php`

Comment: Ah, you're right, it will never be sent without more modifications -)